# string to oracle date in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a string in the format "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm".. i need to convert it into oracle date format 'dd-mon-yy'..... How do i make it happen???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the string sent to oracle??
Use the to_date() function to convert the java string to oracle date.
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: Actually i wish to send the string to a web service which in turn access the database. So i wanted to convert it to the oracle date in java.

Comment: Yeah well you can always pass it as string formatted however, then in oracle just use the to_date(<string>,<same format>) and convert it using the same format.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where the string is, considering the java tag...  Assuming a column value:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(t.column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_char() method of oracle. You can get more information about date conversion [here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an sql query against your database via prepared statment you can use

```
java.sql.Date
```

which stores the Date. Note that this object does not store time, just month, day and year. Also see

```
java.sql.Time
java.sql.Timestamp
```

If you are looking to format the date for display purpose, try

```
java.text.DateFormat
```

Comment: I wish to select particular records based on some date. This date is coming in the form of String from the GUI. So i need to convert to string into oracle date.